# What cognitive architectures out there combine multiple sensor streams?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, cognitive-modeling

It seems like most cognitive architectures are evaluated on toy problems that do not challenge more than one sense (usually the visual one). What neuronal cognitive architectures were evaluated in the more complex case of multiple senses?

Comment: one example of multi-modal integration is that of probabilistic population codes.  see Ma,...,Pouget 2006 Bayesian inference with probabilistic population codes

Comment: also see the work of dora angelaki

Comment: EPIC and ACT-R are two architectures that have similar visual and auditory input channels. I bet they can, and have been combined, for more complex tasks.